# Count DateTime Stamp For Results

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a table containing a list of `userids` and a datetime `stamp` for when a transaction is carried out. It looks like the following:

```
UserId | Stamp   
 John11| 01/01/2013 01:15:27
```

I would like to return a query which shows for a period of time how many transactions each user has done.

I have tried a `count` but due to the time part of the `stamp` it counts for each individual millisecond rather than overall.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is counting the amount of rows okay too? You could try `count(1)` if so.

Comment: Over what period? a day? What have you tried already?

Comment: I have tried to_char(table.DateTimeStamp,'DD-MM-YYYY') as Stamp with
WHERE table.DateTimeStamp >= to_timestamp('01-01-2013', 'DD-MM-YYYY')
  and table.DateTimeStamp <= to_timestamp('03-01-2013', 'DD-MM-YYYY')

Counting the UserId

Comment: So counting the milliseconds is not oke. But on what level do you want the count to happen, seconds/hours/day? 

E.g for counting how many unique day occurences for a specific user: `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT TRUNC(DateTimeStamp) ) FROM MY_TABLE`

Answer (score 0):

Use [time_to_sec](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-time_to_sec-function.php) function for get actual value.

```
Select count(UserId), UserId from table where time_to_sec(stamp) between 
fromTime and toTime
-- fromTime and toTime are interval period
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question does not specify what period you want but here is an example for month which you could adapt to other periods:

```
SELECT 
  (DATEPART(YEAR, Stamp) * 100) + RIGHT('0' + DATEPART(MONTH, Stamp), 2) AS month_group
  ,COUNT(*) AS count
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY
  (DATEPART(YEAR, Stamp) * 100) + RIGHT('0' + DATEPART(MONTH, Stamp), 2)
```

Or for one period only use;

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(*) AS count
FROM MyTable
WHERE Stamp BETWEEN ? AND ?
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 select user_id,count(userid) cnt from table
 where stamp between to_timestamp('01-01-2013 01:15:27', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH:MI:SS') and
 to_timestamp('03-01-2013 12:15:27', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH:MI:SS') 
 group by user_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you want to do the count, something like this should work.

Every unique occurence of dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss for a userid is counted.

```
SELECT userid
,      count(distinct TO_CHAR(stamp, 'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'))
FROM   MYTABLE
where  stamp > to_date('16-03-2013','DD-MM-YYYY')
group by userid
```

Live example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/71241/1